# OpenGL: Is "discard" the only replacement for deprecated GL_ALPHA_TEST?

Tags: opengl

I've just realized that `GL_ALPHA_TEST` was deprecated since OpenGL 3.0, so I can't use it with `glEnable()`. And I've tried quickly to google how to replace it now (and why it was deprecated), but failed to find the answer for this simple question. I also didn't find the information about `GL_ALPHA_TEST` removing in Khronos documentation.

I suggest that now the only way to discard fragments according to their alpha value is the "discard" keyword in fragment shaders. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `GL_ALPHA_TEST` is not in core and you must use `discard` in the fragment shader to get the same effect.

The other alternative is to use a compatibility context, but this is not available on all systems.